# Dual booting Win10/Ubuntu 15.04 starts in grub bash

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a brand-new PC with pre-installed Win10. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a separate hard drive, without any problems.

However, after the first (successful) boot, when I rebooted the machine, the computer went straight to a grub terminal with basic BASH-like commands. When I exit, the machine reboots into grub, and I am able to fire up either OS.

Just to be sure, I re-installed Ubuntu. The exact same behaviour: first boot successful, subsequent boots go to the BASH-like terminal. Exiting leads to normal service being resumed.

This is obviously not a crippling problem, since I can always get to grub and then use my machine. It is annoying, though.

I assume the problem is linked to UEFI, since my other Win10 machine, running old-fashioned BIOS, doesn't suffer from it.

Any suggestions as to what might be the problem, and how it could be solved?

UPDATE:

Here's a [link to a screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/546760/DSCN0460.jpg) of the grub screen (via Dropbox; being newly registered, I'm not allowed to upload photos). This is a new installation, so no other grub installations are present.

Oddly enough, every time I boot into a live USB, the first re-boot afterwards runs without this problem — but only ever once.

Comment: Please post a screen shot (digital photo) of your "bash-like" display. This could be a second GRUB installation that's left over from a previous installation and so is failing; or it could be you're booting into an EFI shell; or maybe even something completely different. A photo will help those of us who know these things recognize what you're seeing.

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: That is saying you are booting a different grub than your working one. Or something left over from before. Is second drive an internal or external drive? Did you install in UEFI or CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode? Best to have lots more detail: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Here's the boot-info link:http://paste.ubuntu.com/12623216/

I installed in UEFI. I have three internal drives: a SSD each for Windows and Ubuntu, and a HDD for personal files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `efibootmgr` output, which shows your boot order:

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0002,0003,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  Vendor(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012,)..BO
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1a,0)USB(1,0)USB(4,0)HD(1,20,ee7fe0,64ad344f)..BO
```

Note that your `BootCurrent` is `0004`, and your `BootOrder` shows `0004` first. This item appears to be a boot of a SanDisk device, probably in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This seems to be `/dev/sdd`, which has evidence of both SYSLINUX and GRUB installed on it. My hunch is that this is the problem -- your system is booting GRUB in BIOS mode from this SanDisk device; then when you exit, it tries additional boot options, starting with `0000` (`ubuntu`), which works.

If I'm right, there are several possible solutions:

- Permanently remove the SanDisk device, or at least remove it when booting. I'm guessing this is a USB flash drive or something similar, based on its size, but I'm not positive of that.
- In Ubuntu, type `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0003,0002,0001` to reset the boot order to omit the SanDisk device and put the working Ubuntu entry first. Given your description, though, this solution might not work permanently; it's possible that your firmware is pusing the SanDisk entry to the top of the list for some reason. This leads to the next possibility....
- Go into your firmware and adjust your settings. Two items in particular bear attention:

  - Disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), aka "legacy boot support" or words to that effect. If I'm right, the problem is a BIOS-mode boot, so disabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support should eliminate the problem.
  - Adjust the boot order within the firmware to elevate the working Ubuntu option (probably `Boot0000`) to the top of the list, and move the SanDisk entry to the bottom or eliminate it entirely.

Unfortunately, I can't be more specific about the firmware settings, since the details of how to enter the firmware setup utility and change its options vary so much from one model to another. In most cases, you can enter the firmware setup utility by hitting Delete, Enter, or a function key as the computer starts up (before GRUB appears). You may need to ask on a forum dedicated to your manufacturer's hardware if you have trouble with this procedure.

---

***EDIT:***

In response to your comments: First, ***forget everything you ever knew about how computers boot!*** You noted that you attempted a "boot sector repair," but that's BIOS thinking. You no longer have a BIOS; you have an EFI. This EFI can boot BIOS-mode OSes via something called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), but your OSes are clearly not installed in this mode. Thus, attempting a BIOS-mode repair option is, at best, an exercise in futility. Worse, if your firmware is set up to enable the CSM, you're complicating your boot path and making everything harder to diagnose. This was the basis of the first sub-option of the third option of my original reply -- disabling the CSM, if it's enabled, may make some problems go away. Thus, I re-iterate that suggestion at this point: Check your firmware settings, and if the CSM (aka "legacy boot support") is enabled, *disable it.*

Next, given your problems, you might want to give my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) a try. You can install it from its Debian package or PPA once you boot Ubuntu. If this is successful, rEFInd will take over as your primary boot program. OTOH, it's possible that whatever's causing your reversion to a non-functional GRUB will continue, in which case rEFInd will become another complication.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the trouble. The last bullet point seems to have done the job. I still find this odd, since the SanDisk USB device was the flash drive I used to install Ubuntu on my system. It's not been present in the machine since installation. And, as I said, when I have booted into the live USB, the machine has always rebooted correctly once (with the SanDisk removed). So I suspect that there's something else going on as well - but nevertheless I've got the machine working for now.

Comment: But only for a moment. After a pair of reboots, the problem recurs. I'm baffled because (as I stated above) the SanDisk stick is in a desk drawer, not connected to the machine. I also tried the efibootmgr solution, with equally little success. I'm almost tempted to do a clean install.

Comment: Try deleting the SanDisk item from the NVRAM list. Assuming the boot numbers haven't changed, `sudo efibootmgr -b 0004 -B` should do the trick. You might want to check the boot order and ensure that `Boot0000` is at the top of the list thereafter. Also, check your manufacturer's site for a firmware (they probably call it a "BIOS") update. What you're describing is clearly a bug, and a firmware update might fix it.

Comment: OK, no joy but more puzzlement. I got fed up and did a clean install of Ubuntu. I also attempted a boot sector repair via Windows installation media, but it reported no problems and did nothing. Now the situation is as follows: if I reboot after login into Windows, grub fires up without a problem. If I reboot after login into Ubuntu, I end up with the "bash-like" display (see original post).  (TBC)

Comment: Here's my current efibootmgr output:  
`BootCurrent: 0000  
Timeout: 1 seconds  
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003,0001  
Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)  
Boot0001* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  Vendor(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012,)..BO  
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)  
Boot0003* ubuntu HD(1,408,82000,7a967035-e35d-4f5d-a27e-c85c9929f966)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)`

Comment: As you can see, I have two 'ubuntu' entries. If I swap them round via UEFI settings, the computer gets stuck in a POST loop. I don't particularly want to start from scratch with both OS's—clean install of Windows, followed by a clean install again of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm afraid this leaves me stumped. BIOS mode is disabled in my hardware settings. Whenever I reboot from Windows, grub starts normally. Whenever I reboot from Ubuntu, I get the non-functional grub. I'm not sure I want to add another layer. Perhaps I just have to put up with a minor irritation.